# Simplifying this in Regex, or the next best way?

Tags: c#, .net

I'm facing an issue today, I want to check if my string is alpha numeric [lower alpha] with the exception or also allowing dashes and dots.

Is there a way, or more corretly said what is a better way to do this to improve efficiency. Right now it seems like its hugely over thought and could be much more simple.

```
// Declare the allowed characters
private static readonly List<char> Allowedchars = new List<char>(new[]
{
    'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l',
    'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x',
    'y', 'z', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '0', '-', '.'
});
```

Check if valid:

```
private static bool isValid(char character)
{
    return Allowedchars.Contains(character);
}
```

The actual method:

```
public static bool IsValidAlphaNumeric(string inputStr)
{
    inputStr = inputStr.ToLower();
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(inputStr))
    {
        return false;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < inputStr.Length; i++)
    {
        if (!isValid(inputStr[i]))
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use ASCII table value instead of loop each letter will be one solution

```
0~9 [48 - 57]
a~z [97 - 122]
.-  [45 - 46]

    string s = "9quali52ty3";
    byte[] ASCIIValues = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(s);
    bool IsValidAlphaNumeric = true;
    foreach (byte b in ASCIIValues)
    {
        if (b < 45 || (b == 47 || (b > 57 && b < 96) || b > 122)){
            IsValidAlphaNumeric = false;
            break;
        }
    }
    Console.WriteLine(IsValidAlphaNumeric);
```

Comment: Use Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(value);to get ASCII code number, and use the number to compare

Comment: See the [ASCII table](http://www.asciitable.com/). Character `0` is 48, `1` is 49, etc. Character `a` is 97, `b` is 98, etc.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a Regex to check if the string is a match.

```
void Main()
{
    IsValid("ABC");   // false
    IsValid("abc");   // true
    IsValid("abc-."); // true
}

public static bool IsValid(string input)
{
    var regex = new Regex(@"[a-z0-9-.]");
    return regex.IsMatch(input);
}
```

Comment: The OP also is checking for numbers 0 through 9 too.